# Jeditable won't show changes or update textarea

Tags: php, jquery, jeditable

I have been experimenting with Jeditable, and i have got it to update normal  tags as .edit... but it will not update

with .editArea
Plus when it updates the normal  the update is not shown until i update the page..

I am not sure what  i am doing wrong, and some help would be appreciated :)

Code:

```
    <div>
<h2 id='<?= $row['id']?>' class="edit"> <?= $row['title']?></h2>
<p class="editArea"><?= $row['Text'] ?></p>
</div>
<?php
```

}
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
        var text = 20;

```
 $('.edit').editable('http://www.JapSeyz.dk/save.php?type=header', {
     indicator : 'Saving...',
     submit : 'OK',
     id   : 'id',
     name : 'value',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
 });
 $('.editArea').editable('http://www.JapSeyz.dk/save.php?type=text', { 
     type      : 'textarea',
     submit    : 'OK',
     id   : 'id',
     name : 'value',
     rows : '6',
     cols : '100',
     indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
 });
```

});
(I left all the require/styling etc out.. )

And the update script

```
<?php
require("Oese/Connection.php");

$type = (isset($_GET['type'])) ? $_GET['type'] : "";
$value = (isset($_POST['value'])) ? $_POST['value'] : "";
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : "";


if($type == "text"){
mysql_query("UPDATE Oese SET Text='$value' WHERE id='$id'");
}
elseif($type == "header"){
mysql_query("UPDATE Oese SET title='$value' WHERE id='$id'");
}
print $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the options you're passing `id : 'id'`, this may be overwriting the value sent by jeditable.

Try removing this and see. Otherwise, `var_dump($_POST)` on the server and see what is actually sent (on Chrome developer toolbar, check the Network tab).

Comment: okay thanks.. Nope, it did not work... :/ It will still update the standard <h2> but i need to update the page for it to show... but it will not update the <p>

Comment: on chrome it sends it, but in network the status is canceled  and type is pending.. but i don't know why it gets canceled

Comment: Having quickly looked at the docs this may help. Your <p> element needs an id="" attribute so the reply can be properly targeted.

Comment: Plus an id attribute must start with a letter, and not a number. Thi could also be causing problems. Try using div_1 then explode() the variable on the server.